# Show carriage return from rails to javascript

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, line-breaks, carriage-return

I have a `.js.erb` which is triggered by a js function.

In this js.erb I have the following code:

```
event = <%=raw @event.to_json %>
$('#preview-event-body').html(event.body);
```

`event.body` is a `TEXT` mysql value and has been stored by a `text_area`

Now, the problem is that this `$('#preview-event-body').html(event.body);` inserts the text as a line and I cannot the breaks('enter' stored by the user).

e.g. the user stores (in mySQL I see the same):

```
text

with a break
```

and the above outputs:

```
text with a break
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to replace carriage-returns to

```
<p></p> or <br />
```

Because sometimes you can see carriage returns but HTML doesn't show them as carriage returns.

If you display result in a textarea, you can see them, otherwise you cannot see them in HTML. Try to replace \r\n with those html tags and see if it changes.

Comment: You can verify it by viewing HTML source, in firefox, press CTRL + U and see if you can see carriage returns. If not, tell me, so I can tell you other solutions

Comment: In source js I can see `"body":"text\r\n        with a break"` . When I inspect it, it looks like it should but without any `<p>` or `<br>`.  In browser's rendered page of course as a line

Comment: So before displaying that text, you have to replace \r\n breaks with <br /> like this: var n=str.replace("\r\n","<br />");

Comment: thank you, it works fine. I worked it a bit and I used: `n = str.replace(/\r\n/g,"<br />");`